# Running shell commands using PHP script

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, command-line

I'm creating an app using CodeIgniter, but I'm unable to run Linux commands using my PHP script.

How do I run terminal commands?

I've tried `shell_exec()` and `exec()`, but both don't work while using CI.

Comment: Which command are you trying to run using exec() ?

Comment: Put the following command in your php code to make sure that command is working: print exec('whoami'); Probably, there is issue with the command you are trying to run. Please provide more details to figure-out the issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. Debugging requests like your post should be posted as a comment.

Comment: sure, i'll take care of that in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on your server configuration if the functions are disabled, you need to enable them in your `php.ini`. Here are some alternatives:

- [`popen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php)
- or if you need an interactive way try [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.proc-open.php)
- [`system()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)

Comment: commands like `ls` and `pwd` are working at their best using `system()` function
but commands like `mkdir` experience an epic failure