# shell commands not working from Codeigniter

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, shell, unix

If i am trying to execute this command from my controller :

```
$output = shell_exec('asterisk -rx "core show channels concise"');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Nothing appears only blank page is showing.
but when i run

```
exec('ls -la', $outputArray);
print_r($outputArray);
```

Output is printed fine.

I tried other methods which are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240411/running-shell-commands-using-php-script). what changes i have to make in my **php.ini** to run **shell commands**.How can I find out what is going wrong when I see no error message right away?

Comment: There may be some error . Redirect err to stdout to capture error : `$output = shell_exec('asterisk -rx "core show channels concise" 2>&1 ');`. Are you seeing any errors ?

Comment: There are lots of possibilities how this can fail (executable not found, missing environment variables which are always set when you log in properly, etc.).  Your question should be rephrased into "How can I find out what is going wrong when I see no error message right away?".

Comment: @Makesh - Error is **Unable to connect to remote asterisk (does /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl exist?)**